# Jquery .click() function selector issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I'm currently building a `PHP` web-page that retrieves data from a `SQL` server and outputs the retrieved data as a table. Each `<tr>` has its own class kind of like this:

```
"<table class='preview'>
      <tr class='title'>
          <th>$pages->title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class='info'>
          <td class='type static'>Type: </td>
          <td class='type dynamic'>$pages->type</td>
          <td class='auteur static'>Written by: </td>
          <td class='auteur dynamic'>$pages->author</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='article'>
          <td colspan='4'>$pages->article</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='btns'>
          <td colspan='4'>
             <button type='button' class='more'>
                  See more
             </button>
             <button type='button' class='less'>
                  See less
             </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>"
```

As there are multiple articles and as they are quite long, I want to hide the articles using `display: none;` until the user clicks on the "see more" button.

I did this with the following jQuery code:

```
var main = function() {
$('#search_container .preview').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('#search_container .active .more').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('#search_container .active .less').show();
    $('#search_container .active .article').show();
    $('#search_container .active .more').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .info').hide();
});

$("#search_container .active .less").click(function(){
    $('#search_container .active .less').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .article').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .more').show();
    $('#search_container .active .info').show();
});
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

As only the selected article needs to be revealed, I decided to add the first function. However the selector for `.active .more` and `.active .less` do not seem to be working since, when I execute the exact same code without the `.active` selector, it works and ALL the articles and buttons are revealed or hidden.

Any idea how I can fix that ?

Comment: Are you sure that the `active` class is added when you hover the element ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `.active` is somewhere up the markup. And OP just needs using `this` or `closest()`.

Comment: `$('#search_container').on('click', '.active .more', function() {`

Comment: @u_mulder thanks - I missed the `hover` event

Comment: Beyond that, `$('#search_container .article')` will match **all** the `<tr class='article'>` elements. You need to use `id`s on your table or some trick using `$(this)` and `parent` or `closest`.

Comment: Just on a semantic note, you should not be using tables here and you have missed the colspan from your `th`

Comment: @Erazihel yes, i used the console to double-check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. This has to do with the scope of the selectors being used. In your javascript what happens is you provide a mechanism for toggling a class, but when you change the class you must re-run your jQuery selectors to find the newly added active class. A few small changes to your javascript code should get you headed in the right direction:

```
var main = function() {
    $('#search_container .preview').hover(
        function(){
            // Keeping this for your targeting
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('.more').click(
                function(){
                    $('#search_container .active .less').show();
                    $('#search_container .active .article').show();
                    $('#search_container .active .more').hide();
                    $('#search_container .active .info').hide();
                }
            );
            $(this).find('.less').click(
                function(){
                    $('#search_container .active .less').hide();
                    $('#search_container .active .article').hide();
                    $('#search_container .active .more').show();
                    $('#search_container .active .info').show();
                }
            );
        },
        // When exiting hover, unbind the click bindings
        function(){
            // Keeping this for your targeting
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            // These keep only one .preview container bound to the commands
            // at a given moment
            $(this).find('.more').unbind('click');
            $(this).find('.less').unbind('click');
        }
    );
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

This implementation has a couple of drawbacks. Each time you hover the click event is registered. Each time you blur off of it the click bindings are unset to prevent a subsequent hover double-binding the click event. Since all of your targeted classes are contained within `.preview` I would go as far as to do something like this:

```
var main = function() {
    var previews = $('#search_container .preview');

    $.each(
        previews,
        function(){

            // Reference stored for the .preview container
            var ref = $(this);

            ref.find('.more').click(
                function(){
                    ref.find('.less').show();
                    ref.find('.article').show();
                    ref.find('.more').hide();
                    ref.find('.info').hide();
                }
            );

            ref.find('.less').click(
                function(){
                    ref.find('.less').hide();
                    ref.find('.article').hide();
                    ref.find('.more').show();
                    ref.find('.info').show();
                }
            );
        }
    );
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Now all of the previews will have their `.more` and `.less` items bound to a click event and the click event operates within the scope of the `.preview` allowing them all to be registered at once. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. And it is very well explained. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is, when you create the event listeners, DOM nodes are not ready yet. Because there are no elements has active class. Instead try the script below

```
var main = function() {
$('#search_container .preview').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('#search_container').on('click', '.active .more', function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('#search_container .active .less').show();
    $('#search_container .active .article').show();
    $('#search_container .active .more').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .info').hide();
});

$('#search_container').on('click', '.active .less', function(){
    $('#search_container .active .less').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .article').hide();
    $('#search_container .active .more').show();
    $('#search_container .active .info').show();
});
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

This will add a `live` event listener on main container and waits for any element matches `.active .more`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're dynamically adding/removing the `.active` class. On load of the page it does not exist on any elements, so no event handlers are bound.

To fix this, use a delegated event handler:

```
var main = function() {
  $('#search_container .preview').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('#search_container').on('click', '.active .more', function() {
    $(this).find('.active .less, .active .article').show();
    $(this).find('.active .more, .active .info').hide();
  }).on('click', '.active .less', function() {
    $(this).find('.active .less, .active .article').hide();
    $(this).find('.active .more, .active .info').show();
  });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: I don't believe so as if you click `.more` twice it would hide the elements again

Comment: Okay, missed it.

Comment: this still doesn't work :s
got the idea of why it doesn't though